# how do URIs with "file" scheme work in Android

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, file-uri

I know that in Android I can read files from disk this way:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("file:///data/data/com.example.mytest.mytest/test.txt");
InputStream stream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
int i;
while ((i = stream.read()) != -1) {
  Log.i("@@@", "znak: " + i);
}
```

However, I don't know how it works. Does exist in Android some content provider that works with "file" scheme? But how - I thought that the scheme of URIs of all content providers must have "content" scheme?

Comment: see http://androidxref.com/5.1.0_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/content/ContentResolver.java#628

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` handle `file:` schemes directly. This is covered in [the documentation for `openInputStream()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#openInputStream%28android.net.Uri%29).

Also, **do not hardcode paths**. Your `Uri` is wrong on millions of devices:

- on Android 4.2+ tablets and Android 5.0+ phones, for guest and other secondary accounts
- on Android M devices, if the user "adopts" removable storage and moves apps to it